# what is the minimum value of $|z+1/2|$?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number such that $|z| \ge 2$, then what is the minimum value of $|z+1/2|$ ?
  Can you give a simple solution as i'm a high school student?

Comment: $\vert z+\frac{1}{2} \vert$ is the distance of the complex $z$ to the point $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $z$ is forced to be outside the disk centered on $0$ and of radius $2$.

Comment: I do not see why this problem should receive down votes.  So it is a simple problem, but I just read on the Meta that there is NO problem to simple mathematically for MSE!

Comment: @TrevorRichards I voted to close this question, because the post doesn't not show any effort to solve the problem, just requesting a solution. Simple question is OK, but effort is required.

Answer (score 4):

By triangle inequality,
$$
3/2\le|z|-|1/2|\le |z+1/2|
$$
and $z=-2$ holds the equality.